# t-SQL what is the maximum number of tables I am able to join?

Tags: sql-server, join

What is the maximum number of tables I am able to join? Or is it unlimited?

Are there any shortcuts to add multiple tables, without having to alias and choose each field?

Comment: You've asked two questions, one of which at least is answered elsewhere, the other is not clear.

Comment: If you need to ask "what is the maximum number of tables I am able to join?" - it's either homework or you are doing something wrong...(or asking the wrong question) Also, a search engine would answer this. Please use one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very bad form (using `*`) but you can simply keep adding tables with out specifying columns as so:

```
select * from table1 
inner join table2 on table1.id1 = table2.id2;
```

add another table by changing the above to:

```
select * from table1 
inner join table2 on table1.id1 = table2.id2 
inner join table3 on table3.id3=table2.id2;
```

The problem with such a join is that you are probably getting too many columns and moving data around unnecessarily is what kills performance. You don't take out all your clothes from your closet when you are looking for shirts (I hope).